# Assign output of expanded pandas str.extract to new columns of same dataframe when rows are filtered with .loc

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe with some registration types and some alphanumeric registration numbers for certain types. If a row has a certain type, I need to perform a regex operation on the relevant number, potentially splitting it into two, and return two columns based on that operation to the original dataframe. I am receiving a warning about setting values based on slices and an instruction to use `.loc` instead, but doing so voids my output column for reasons I cant understand.

Using the slice method:

```py
data = [['5007', 'foo'], 
       ['5008', '1111111'],
       ['5008', '00222222'],
       ['5008', '333333'],
       ['5007', 'BAR'],
       ['5008', 'SC444444'],
       ['5008', 'SC5555'],
       ['5008', 'LP6666'],
       ['5008', '7777-8888'],
       ['5007', 'foobar']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['reg_type', 'reg_no'])
filter = (df['reg_type'] == '5008')
df[['code', 'number']] = df.loc[filter]['reg_no'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)?(.+$)', expand=True)
```

This gives the output

|  | reg_type | reg_no | code | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5007 | foo | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 5008 | 1111111 | NaN | 1111111 |
| 2 | 5008 | 00222222 | NaN | 00222222 |
| 3 | 5008 | 333333 | NaN | 333333 |
| 4 | 5007 | BAR | NaN | NaN |
| 5 | 5008 | SC444444 | SC | 444444 |
| 6 | 5008 | SC5555 | SC | 5555 |
| 7 | 5008 | LP6666 | LP | 6666 |
| 8 | 5008 | 7777-8888 | NaN | 7777-8888 |
| 9 | 5007 | foobar | NaN | NaN |

This is correct, but it also produces the warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Modifying to what I think the `.loc` method should be:

```py
data = [['5007', 'foo'], 
        ['5008', '1111111'],
        ['5008', '00222222'],
        ['5008', '333333'],
        ['5007', 'BAR'],
        ['5008', 'SC444444'],
        ['5008', 'SC5555'],
        ['5008', 'LP6666'],
        ['5008', '7777-8888'],
        ['5007', 'foobar']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['reg_type', 'reg_no'])
filter = (df['reg_type'] == '5008')
df.loc[filter, ['code', 'number']] = df.loc[filter]['reg_no'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)?(.+$)', expand=True)
```

This produces the output

|   |reg_type   |reg_no |code   |number|
|---|-----------|-------|-------|------|
|0  |5007   |foo    |NaN    |NaN|
|1  |5008   |1111111    |NaN    |NaN|
|2  |5008   |00222222   |NaN    |NaN|
|3  |5008   |333333 |NaN    |NaN|
|4  |5007   |BAR    |NaN    |NaN|
|5  |5008   |SC444444   |NaN    |NaN|
|6  |5008   |SC5555 |NaN    |NaN|
|7  |5008   |LP6666 |NaN    |NaN|
|8  |5008   |7777-8888  |NaN    |NaN|
|9  |5007   |foobar |NaN    |NaN|
The output of the `extract` has been voided. I have also tried to append `reset_index()` to the end of the extract command but that produced no change.

How can I satisfy achieving this with `.loc`?

Comment: Most likely this is coming from a preceding code. Your [mre] doesn't produce this error.

Comment: In pandas using chained indexing when you see '][' like this, you are likely to get SettingWithCopy Warnings.  Rewrite your line like this `df[['code', 'number']] = df.loc[filter, 'reg_no'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)?(.+$)', expand=True)` using row_indexer (boolean indexing in this case), column_indexer.

Comment: I'm not sure how it can be, as I wrote the MWE from scratch as I have been premature about posting before and the only other line of code that precedes it is `import pandas as pd`, and the only line that follows is `df`. However, I will note that the warning doesnt show on every environment - the `.loc` voiding of the output dos though. The duplicate question that was associated with this one confirmed that the warning can be ignored safely in this use case.

Comment: @ScottBoston That did the trick. I had become fixated on the terms to the left of the `=`. My issue was partly on the right. Thank you.